# How can i get date like this one Fri, 01 Oct 22:26:23 +0200 2011

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Can anybody help me get this date format like `Fri, 01 Oct 22:26:23 +0200 2011`.

Comment: Have you had a look at [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) [two](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) links? If not, please do it, you should be able to solve this yourself. If you had a look and still can't figure it out, please specify in your question what exactly you have tried and what the problem is.

Comment: @Oded: I was checking http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: And what was the problem with that? What did you not understand? What were you having difficulties with? And _what did you try_ after reading that article?

Comment: @Oded: After using Console.WriteLine("{0:ddd, dd MMM HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy}", DateTime.Now); i am getting +05:30 (zzzz). I dont know whether this is correct. Actually i need to send date in this format to an application in J2ME.

Comment: What timezone are you at? Is it indeed at GMT +05:30?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can live with a slightly different format, you can use this format:

```
{0:ddd, dd MMM HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy}
```

It will output

```
Do, 22 Mrz 14:18:41 +03:30 2012
```

instead of

```
Do, 22 Mrz 14:18:41 +0330 2012
```